# error TS2322: Type 'Product' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any>| null |undefined'.<div *ngFor="let product1 of productList" class="col mb-5">

Tags: angular

```
<section class="py-5">
   <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5 mt-5">
      <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-xl-4 justify-content-center">
         <div *ngFor="let product1 of productList" class="col mb-5">
            <div class="card h-100">
               <!-- Product image-->
               <img class="card-img-top" src="{{product1.productImg}}" alt="..." />
               <!-- Product details-->
               <div class="card-body p-4">
                  <div class="text-center">
                     <!-- Product name-->
                     <h5 class="fw-bolder">Fancy Product</h5>
                     <!-- Product price-->
                     $40.00 - $80.00
                  </div>
               </div>
               <!-- Product actions-->
               <div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
                  <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto" href="#">View options</a></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Component Changes:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Product } from '../product';
    import { ProductService } from '../product.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-view-all-product',
      templateUrl: './view-all-product.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./view-all-product.component.css']
    })
    export class ViewAllProductComponent implements OnInit {
      productList : Product;
    
      constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.productService.viewProduct().subscribe(data => {
          data.productList =data;
        })
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As the error message mentioned, `productList` is an **object** but **not array**. `*ngFor` requires array. To improve your question by formatting code and providing question details, I suggest you read the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change

````
this.productService.viewProduct().subscribe(data => {
          data.productList =data;
        })```

    to 

```this.productService.viewProduct().subscribe(data => {
          this.productList =data;
        })
````